# How to delete TFVC repository on Azure Devops?

Tags: azure-devops, tfvc, azure-repos

I have 2 repositories linked to a project in Azure DevOps.

One repository is GIT and the other is TFVC. I wanted to try out TFVC, but turns out I will continue with GIT for support purposes. So I want to delete the TFVC repository on the project.

I understand that deleting the project will remove the repository, this is not an option for me.

I also know the following command : "tf vc destroy $/TestProject" removes the repository but it is not being removed from Devops completely which is a problem for me.

Other posts seem to be from 2018 about this subject. Is there anything added yet to simply remove a TFVC repository from a project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way is to delete the project and recreate it. Otherwise, `destroy` is your best option.

Comment: Sad, but clear. Thanks